# reading from file, gcount() is always 0 even after several file.get()

Tags: c++, io

I'm trying to read from a file using `file.get()` but it seems to be stuck in the first line.
Input file is like:

```
1234,56
7891,01
.......
```

This is my code:

```
char* n1 = new char[5];
char* n2 = new char[3];
std::ifstream data("input_file");
while (i < 4) {
    data.get(n1, 5);
    printf("%ld\n", data.gcount());
    data.get(n2, 3);
    printf("%ld\n", data.gcount());
    //read newline
    data.get(&ch, 2);
    printf("%ld\n", data.gcount());
    printf("n1= %s, n2 = %s\n", n1, n2+1);
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
n1= 1234, n2 = 56
0
0
0
n1= 1234, n2 = 56
0
0
0
n1= 1234, n2 = 56
```

I'm not able to make any sense of this.

Comment: How is `ch` defined ? My guess is that it's only a single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get(char*, streamsize) gets stuck as soon as it encounters newline delimiter.
you need to use getline() to advance to the next line.

Also, your second get() only reads 2 characters from the stream (i.e you will read ",5" instead of ",56" for your first line.

Comment: But why does gcount() return zero always ? shouldn't it increase ?

Comment: @vivek Yes, if it actually extracts something. Once it gets stuck on end-of-line, it won't extract anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem here:

```
data.get(&ch, 2);
```

assuming that you have defined `ch` somewhere earlier as

```
char ch;
```

The newline will be stored in `ch` but a terminating `'\0'` will be written at the next address beyond `ch`, corrupting whatever variable happens to reside there.

Change this to:

```
char ch[2];

data.get(ch, 2);
```

Comment: True, but even after correcting this, he still won't get past the first line unless he either uses getline() or another form of get().

The delimiting character is not extracted from the input sequence if found, and remains there as the next character to be extracted from the stream (see getline for an alternative that does discard the delimiting character).